# How to disable the checkbox always to open with this application on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, regedit

How to disable the option: Always use the selected program to open this type of file ? I tried in the following ways below:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Unknown\shell\opendlg\command
```

but I can't find **opendlg** in the windows 10 pro registry

Creating a default key value:

```
% SystemRoot% \ system32 \ rundll32.exe% SystemRoot% \ system32 \ shell32.dll, OpenAs_RunDLL% 1% 2
```

in this method described above the (open with) checkbox would be disabled (always use this application).

I also tried this other method below:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \ SOFTWARE \ Microsoft \ Windows \ CurrentVersion \ Policies \ Explorer
```

And I created a new *DWORD* **NoFileAssociated** value and set its value to 1.
In this method the checkbox would be completely removed.

All of this works well in previous versions.

Comment: I have the same question, It's very annoying to have to keep unchecking this box